# Getting connection time out while doing ssh on linux server from oracle cloud shell . It shows FIPS mode initialized and then it gets timed out again

Tags: ssh, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-cloud-shell

Getting connection time out while doing ssh on linux server from oracle cloud shell . It shows FIPS mode initialized and then it gets timed out again.

```
kk@cloudshell:~$ ssh -i sshkey.pem opc@xx.x.x.x
FIPS mode initialized
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.x.x port 22: Connection timed out
kk@cloudshell:~ $
```

sshkey.pem is the private key file here to connect to linux server

Answer (score 0):

Same error

```
user@cloudshell:.ssh (region)$ ssh -vvv opc@168.xxx.xxx.xx
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
FIPS mode initialized
debug2: resolving "168.xxx.xxx.xxx" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 168.xxx.xxx.xxx [168.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
^C

Same error to Private/Public IP
user@cloudshell:.ssh (sa-saopaulo-1)$ ssh opc@192.
FIPS mode initialized
```

Comment: It's not an answer actually. It's better to just post answers here in order to keep the content of the thread clean and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

The Private IP of a compute instance cannot be accessed directly on OCI Cloud Shell over SSH. You need to use OCI Cloud Shell Private Networking which allows you to connect a Cloud Shell session to a private network so that you can access resources in your private network without having the network traffic flow over public networks.

For more information, see Cloud Shell Private Networking and Securely access private resources from OCI Cloud Shell using private network access